# Does Subversion have a feature/extension analogous to "hg record"?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

"hg record" is a feature of the hg (a.k.a. Mercurial) revision control system where you can separate changes in different regions of a file (different diff hunks) into different commits.

Does Subversion have something analogous? Perhaps in the form of an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion lets you create [changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.changelists.html) to group multiple distinct changes you've made in a working copy, that you want to commit separately. However, all changes in a given file will be committed; you cannot label individual hunks in a file.

I am not aware of any "extensions" to Subversion.

The way I typically deal with this situation is to check out a second fresh working copy, manually bring into the second working copy those changes I want to commit now (using my text editor's visual diff feature), then commit them. Then delete the second working copy, or keep it around for other future changes. And "svn update" in the first working copy to bring it up to date.

Ideally, avoid getting into the situation by making changes for separate purposes in separate working copies to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use a mercurial/subversion bridge and do your work in mercurial as you normally would and push to the subversion repository.